# Call custom archive program through Windows Explorer context menue

Tags: windows, explorer

I mount a Linux SMB  on Windows. The Linux SMB server is configured to support 
 case-sensitive filenames. The Linux SMB share contains sourcefiles with some files like:

`$ ls dir
test.txt  Test.txt  TesT.txt`

Windows File Explorer handles these files correctly. When I copy them via Ctr-c or move them they are handled as expected.

I now want to *archive* some of the directories from Windows File Explorer through right-click and selecting a archive action in the ***context menue***. The sourcetree is very big and I dont want to navigate via cmdline.

So for I discovered that:

- WinRar only supports case-sensitive filesnames in archives when selecting 'Add to archive...' and then selecting `zip` format. For `Rar` format it will complain with same lowercase names.
- 7zip does not support case-sensitive filesnames at all in any format. It always compains.

Because I am used to `tar.gz` I would rather like to have tar.gz beeing created.  So I have these questions:

- Is there a archive program that registers a context menue action in Windows File Explorer that creates **tar.gz|tar.bz2** and support case-sensitive filenames?
- Is there maybe a possibility to register my own Windows File Explorer **plugin**, maybe written as a JScript, that make it possible for me to call for instance **cygwin**'s `tar -czvf dirname.tar.gz dirname` through the context menue and get the file/dirname as an argument? That would be the prefered solution if it is not too difficult to write/register such a plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the registry to add a context menue:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ArchiveTarGz]
@="[> Archive tar.gz "

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ArchiveTarGz\command]
@="\"C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\mintty.exe\" \"-i\" \"/Cygwin-Terminal.ico\" \"/bin/bash\" \"--login\" \"-i\" \"-c\" \"sh /cygdrive/c/ctxmenue.sh '%1' gz\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ArchiveTarBz2]
@="[> Archive tar.bz2 "

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ArchiveTarBz2\command]
@="\"C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\mintty.exe\" \"-i\" \"/Cygwin-Terminal.ico\" \"/bin/bash\" \"--login\" \"-i\" \"-c\" \"sh /cygdrive/c/ctxmenue.sh '%1' bz2\""
```

Save the above in `r.reg` and execute. Also create `/cygdrive/c/ctxmenue.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

f=$(cygpath -u "${1//\\/\\\\}")
d=$(dirname "$f")
b=$(basename "$f")

case ${2} in
    gz)  ( cd "$d"; tar -cvzf "${b}.tar.${2}" "${b}" );;
    bz2) ( cd "$d"; tar -cvjf "${b}.tar.${2}" "${b}" );;
    *)   ( cd "$d"; tar -cvf "${b}.tar" "${b}" );;
esac
```